# how to deal with synchronizing 2 consecutive REST calls on the same object

Tags: rest, concurrency, stateless

I am having some UI problem that causes it to send 2 put requests one after the other at the same time.

The problem is that the REST API, which does a PUT action compares an object from the database with the object sent by the UI, and updates accordingly (lets say i have added an item to the shopping cart)

Because these 2 calls are at the same time, the second call grabs the object from the database before the first call was able to modify it, causing the added item to be added twice instead of once.

Lets put the UI problem aside for the sake of argument, this is a general synchronization problem in a stateless environment, i would like to know some of the conventions to handle this problem

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What I did in my project is create a modified (a long that is the timestamp) field on every entity in the application. In order for PUT (or any other modification command) to succeed the client needs to send the last (the one in the database) modified value. If the business logic finds that the modified in the database is the same as the client sent - the server performs the action otherwise, rejects it with a proper (custom) error.

2 things needed for this to work:

1. The business logic code needs to be synchronized (not a good thing if you need high performance on updates).
2. The client needs to do a GET before PUT in order to be updated with the last modified value (it probably does cause it (probably) showed the entity to a user anyway before the modification action).

Hope this helps + there might be a more standard way of doing this which I am not aware of.